# How to overload constructors/functions when declarations/parameters are the same?

Tags: c++, constructor-overloading

I would like to create a class to manage the matrices and I met problem with the constructor.
The aim is to find the shortest way to call a constructor of a Matrix objet knowing that some of the constructors have the same header as staying clear.
This is the idea of what I try to get :

```
Matrix id; // create identity matrix
Matrix scale(x, y, z); // create directly a scale matrix
Matrix translation(x, y, z) // create a translation matrix
...
```

Here, all the parameters are `float`s so I cannot overload the constructor, the only thing I see is to use templates but only for those special cases then I don't know what to do.

**Solution**

Finally I decided to make an abstract class like this :

```
class _Mat
{
    public :
        virtual ~_Mat(void) = 0;

        // ...
}

class Mat : public _Mat
{
    public :
        Mat(void);
        virtual ~Mat(void);

        class Scale : public _Mat
        {
            public :
                Scale(float x, float y, float z);
                vitual ~Scale(void);

                // ...
        }

        // ...
}
```

All will be defined into `_Mat` and the other class will just be usefull for their constructor(s)

Finally, we can call constructors like this :

```
Mat id;
Mat::Scale scale(2, 2, 2);
// ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at inheritance.

Comment: But classes will be the same, it's juste the constructor that change and it's weird to create for example "MatrixScale" which is the same that "Matrix" with just a different constructor

Comment: Pleas clarify your question as its not clear what you want. `Matrix<Scale>` and `Matrix<Translation>` are different types and no overload occurs here.

Comment: Ok now it's clear what you want. But you completely misunderstand constrictor concept. Constructor is a method that creates class Matrix not Scale or Translation. If you want to create Scale (or any other object connected to Matrix) there are multiple options here. Some of them Mike Nakis posted in his answer. And if you do not need to create Matrixes dynamically I also would chose builder methods as HolyBlackCat shown in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep it simple and use static member functions:

```
struct Matrix
{
    // ...

    static Matrix Translate(float x, float y, float z) {/*...*/}
    static Matrix Scale(float x, float y, float z) {/*...*/}
};

// ...

Matrix m = Matrix::Scale(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me an idea with the referencing operator

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for *tag dispatching*. You can see it used in the standard library, for example in the overloads of [`std::pair`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

You just have to declare a "tag" struct, which is used to guide overload resolution:

```
struct translation_matrix_tag_t {} static translation_matrix_tag;
struct scale_matrix_tag_t {} static scale_matrix_tag;
```

And then overload your constructors:

```
struct Matrix {

    Matrix(translation_matrix_tag_t, float, float, float);
    Matrix(scale_matrix_tag_t, float, float, float);

    // ...
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
void foo() {
    Matrix m1{translation_matrix_tag, x, y, z};
    Matrix m2{scale_matrix_tag, x, y, z};
}
```

Comment: But we send a new parameter just to specify what we want to use with this solution no ?

Comment: @Zone31 yes, that's what we do.

Comment: there is not a way to call the constructor without adding a useless parameter for the body of the constructor ?

Comment: @Zone31 it holds just as much information as the other parameters, namely how they should be interpreted. But if that really irks you, you can use factory functions instead. They're nice too.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following options:

1. Introduce different dummy parameters of different types in the constructors to differentiate between the overloads.  It is hacky, I would not recommend it.
2. Use inheritance.  Create different subclasses where each one of them is named after the functionality provided by its constructor.
3. Make your constructor private and introduce `public static` factory methods that have nice and long names that clearly indicate what they do.  (No overloading.)

Personally, I would go with the 3rd choice.